# how to use physical key like volume button and power button in windows phone app programming

Tags: c#, windows, uwp

My project is related to creating windows phone application using C# . I want to use volume button(physical key) to call event in my project. I need some reference  to do that.

Comment: Eldho i have not started to code yet. I think my app is based mostly on usage of physical key and I don't know how to use physical key in programming

Comment: Volume keys are unavailable, but the camera and back button can be listened to. Check the link.

Answer (score 1):

This is not permitted as these buttons are reserved by the OS. Not only would using them be potentially confusing by people using the app ("How do I turn down the music I'm listening to while using the app?") but would also interfere with some of the reset commands for devices.

The only buttons you can use for anything are the back button (but don't mess with standard navigation behavior) and the camera button (if it exists.)